# Using excel 2010 VBA, a sub was just not running after the line: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:AL60").Clear. Can this be fixed?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

publicColumn is declared in the module as

```
Public publicColumn As Range
```

The full sub was:

```
Sub DoAll()
    'Stop
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:AL60").Clear
    If Sheets("Model").Range("E1") = "KG" Then
        Set publicColumn = Sheets("Model").Range("H7")
    Else
        Set publicColumn = Sheets("Model").Range("H6")
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    AddFlavors.Show
    Sheets("Model").Activate
End Sub
```

I was able to get this to work by changing to the following:

```
Sub DoAll()
    'Stop
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:AL60").Clear
    Sheets("Model").Activate
    If Sheets("Model").Range("E1") = "KG" Then
        Set publicColumn = Sheets("Model").Range("H7")
    Else
        Set publicColumn = Sheets("Model").Range("H6")
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    AddFlavors.Show
    Sheets("Model").Activate
End Sub
```

Why would this just exit the sub/stop executing? Was it something wrong with my code?

It was being run via a button on Sheet("Model") but I also tried running it through the step through debugger which is how I found where it was exiting.

---

Edit: The adjustments don't seem have fixed anything. I know since I can't specifically repeat the conditions in which the code fails it becomes very difficult to debug. If anyone has ideas as to what is causing this let me know.

Comment: Well one thing, you have toggled off `ScreenUpdating` so maybe it is running.

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should really be toggled back to `True`

Comment: After declaring your variables, I was able to step through the code from start to end. Do you have a `Worksheet_Change` event on `Sheet1` by any chance?

Comment: Does the code error out? What happens when you step through? Does it jump right to `End Sub`? Does it step to a line in a different sub/module?

Comment: The calls to `.Activate` should be completely unnecessary - does it continue if you comment out the `.Clear` call?

Comment: The debugger stopped running entirely after I stepped through the .Clear call so screen updating wouldn't affect it.

Comment: Code just stops running no error message no step to another line

Comment: There is a worksheet selection event on sheets("formula") but my code doesn't touch that sheet

Comment: Let's start with the "Silly questions":  Do you actually have a sheet named "Sheet 1"?  Is the range you are clearing protected? Is the sheet protected?  Here's a "less silly" question:   Have you used "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" in any other places and not turned it back on (this could cause messages critical to this error to not be displayed)?

Comment: I have not suppressed the alerts. The obvious culprits you mentioned are all fine. The weirdest part is that even when it fails to execute, it clears the range first

Comment: This code is not the problem. Check for office updates. Then copy just this code to a new workbook for testing.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Since the error didn't occur every time in the past, it is hard to know for sure but I haven't run into it since.